# How to link the "official" GitHub instance with IntelliJ?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm not entirely sure if this question is right on this Stack, so please don't be angry if it doesn't belong here, just move it over.

I'm using GitHub via the "official" instance provided from the GitHub main page. Recently I started using IntelliJ, and I wanted to use my Git instance within the IntelliJ Git integration.

The trouble is that the "official" Git instance is somewhat...... weirdly installed. There is no mention of "Git" or "GitHub" to find in my program files, neither in the "normal" ones nor in the x86 ones. Instead, my AppData\Local folder is full with GitHub stuff I tried navigating for lots of time, but IntelliJ wasn't getting along with any of the EXEs I found there. When I right-click the desktop shortcuts, no "Open file path" appears either. I tried opening the shortcuts in the editor and copypasting the paths into my file explorer, but that just led to the AppData Git chaos once again. Can anyone help me out?﻿

Comment: What do you mean by "official instance"?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The one you can get on the GitHub main page. By now I found the right executable, though. It actually was in this chaos built into `AppData\Local\GitHub` and `AppData\Local\Apps\github-...`.

Comment: Still I don't know what "instance" you are talking about. A repository, some executable somewhere or what?

Comment: An executable, plus the resource bundle it needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I searched thoroughly, but not thoroughly enough. In the folder `C:\Users\root\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit<some-random-numbers>`, there was a subfolder called `cmd` I overlooked several times before. The right executable was `git.exe` from that very folder.

For others running into the same problem, here is the full copiable path (just replace `<user>` with your username):

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_d7effa1a4a322478cd29c826b52a0c118ad3db11\cmd\git.exe
```

Comment: In case you wonder, that was the solution. I'm just not yet able to accept it.